# Get facebook public events based on location by using Facebook - Graph Api or FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Hello friends I was trying to get all the facebook public events by using graph api or fql.
something link here : allevents.in.

but couldn't manage to find the exact way which can get me a location based events. can you guys help me how to find the location based events from the facebook.